# Avoid existing folders and bring only folders that don't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code below which is bringing attachments into parent_directory using api connection.

Problem: The code works great but the only problem with this code is it gets stuck when there're existing folders.

Solution: How can make this code bypass the existing folders. So if the folder exists, then don't do anything just move to the next loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import zipfile

parent_directory = "folderpath"
csv_file_dir = "myfilepath.csv"

user = "API_username"
key = "API_password"

os.chdir(parent_directory)
bdr_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file_dir)
api_first = "… " + user + ":" + key + "…"

for index, row in bdr_data.iterrows():
    #print(row['url_attachment'])
    name = row['Ref_Num']
    os.makedirs(parent_directory + name)
    os.chdir(parent_directory + name)
    url = api_first + row['url_attachment'] + " -o attachments.zip"
    os.system(url)
    os.chdir(parent_directory)
```

Comment: Use `os.listdir()` to get the folders, and check whether the folder exists before calling `makedirs()`

Comment: Use `os.path.exists` or `os.path.isdir`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
for index, row in bdr_data.iterrows():
    name = row['Ref_Num']
    child_dir = (parent_directory + name)
    if os.path.exists(child_dir):  # check if folder exist.
        print(f'{child_dir} already exist')  # you may want to know what is skipped
        continue  # skip iteration.
    os.makedirs(child_dir)  # if folder not found, do what you need.
```